# Interdiction vs Interception?

Tags: differences, nouns

What's the difference between *interception* and *interdiction*?

Their definition seems the same to me?

Comment: One distinction is that *intercept* tends to carry a more physical action of blockage, while *interdict* is more of a "verbal" blockage (coming from the root *dict-*, meaning speak). In practice, *interdict* is sometimes used in a physical sense, but it's roots are in speech.

Comment: Interdiction has a special defintion in the military "Interdiction is an action to divert, disrupt, delay, or destroy the enemy’s military surface capability
before it can be used effectively against friendly forces or to achieve enemy objectives." [Joint Interdiction](https://fas.org/irp/doddir/dod/jp3_03.pdf). So contrary to the above, in the military, it tends to get kinda physical.

Answer (score 2):

*Interdict* originally meant to forbid something. If something is forbidden, it can sometimes also legally be seized, and this is an extension of the original meaning.

*Intercept* originally meant to seize something on its route from one place to another.

So for seizing things that are illegal, you can use either.

> They interdicted the drugs the cartel was shipping across the border.
> They intercepted the drugs the cartel was shipping across the border.

But for seizing things that are legal, you should only use *intercept*.

> The enemy intercepted our messages; don't go to the rendezvous.

Answer (score 0):

"Interdiction," is derived from two Latin words: **inter** and **dictum**. "Inter dictum" literally translates as "the things having been said/indicated between." 
"Interception," is derived from two Latin words: **inter** and **ceptum**. "Inter ceptum" literally translates as the "the things having been taken/seized between." 
You might feel that the definitions in the English dictionary are similar, but once we understand their origins, their differences are apparent:
that the one is about indicating something between two or more entities, and that the other is about taking something from between two or more entities.

Interdiction is claiming something about things (like prohibiting something) and interception is the act of stopping things from happening, or seizing the things in between and controlling them. I hope this helped.

Comment: The etymology apart, what can *interdict* claim? Can you provide a definition that broadens the meaning from  *forbid/prohibit/preclude* to  just *claim*?